# What is the advantage of using a Django bootstrap module over linking to bootstrap files directly?

Tags: python, django

I see there are Django bootstrap modules (e.g. crispy_forms, django_bootstrap).  I am trying to decide whether to use a module or link directly to bootstrap files in a base html file like the following:

```
<!-- jQuery library --> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript --> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script
```

I have an understanding that with the modules I would do the styling in the code. With using bootstrap directly, I am thinking I have to style it in the template files.

I am trying to see reasons why I should be using a module.  Also, with the bootstrap modules would I be able to use all bootstrap features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using modules for bootstrap is an awful idea. It creates tight coupling between ur app and the css framework. If you ever decide to move to a different framework you’ll need to refactor your forms in addition to the html templates. This also applies if you decide to upgrade from bootstrap3 to bootstrap4 in the future. Bootstrap4 has a ton of backward incompatible changes.

Create a form rendering template snippet and reuse that everywhere you need a form. If you want to change or upgrade cas later, all you have to do is update that one file.

Comment: what you say has been one of my concerns. I am going to try out direct use of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The django-bootstrap modules provides a set of convenience template tags and integration with existing django features such as forms.

For instance, styling and rendering a django form in a template with bootstrap styling is as simple as

```
{% bootstrap_form form %}
```

As for upgrading to bootstrap4, django-boostrap4 is available.

Of course nothing is forcing you to use the django bootstrap module if you prefer to manually write your own bootstrap HTML tag class names and that might be better for your specific use case.